# Power Query Connection to outsource excel files

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am currently working on an excel file("Main") that has two sources of input from other excel files. So we have 3 excel files. ("Main", "Source A", "Source B").

Source A: Load the table in a power query (from Source A to our Main file), follow some transformations on the data and Load the results into a tab in the Main file.

Source B: Load the table in a power query (from Source B to our Main file), follow some transformations on the data and Load the results into a tab in the Main file.

The problem arises when we wish to update the queries (some but not all).

The transformations performed are intensive and a refresh of the queries does take some time.

It seems that when an update is performed in queries that do the transformations on data from Source A, the queries that relate to transformations on data from Source B also update. Since no change is performed on Source B we do not want the refreshing to occur there.

My question is about how could we manage this? (i.e. update the queries that actually relate to changes made at that specific time)

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: How do you exactly update the queries? (which menu, which button etc.)

Comment: I noticed this occurring when working in one of the queries that relate to the Source A and pressing on Close and Load button  to load changes made. And then I can see that all queries are being refreshed..~(Data>Show Queries I can see queries updating on the right pane that appears)

Comment: When you use **Close & Load** from Power Query it refreshes all of the data. Try right clicking on a Query and refreshing from that right pane; this way only the selected item will be refreshed. (or alternatively when on the resulting table, use **Data/Refresh All/Refresh** button, again only the active data will be refreshed, not all of them)